# Are there any easy-to-configure webserver with ruby for Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, webserver, sinatra

Are there any easy-to-configure webserver with ruby for Windows ?

I am hoping to find a webserver that can easily be configured to work with Ruby on Rails or Sinatra.

Anyone know of any ?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), and [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), both are sibling sites of this one. They are more server oriented and can give you good information on alternate solutions and their set-up.

Comment: Also checkout http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com)+[Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) on Windows, sometimes behind either [Apache](http://www.apache.org/) or [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) as a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (to speed up serving static files and to create a pool of 2-4 server instances). The speed is not as good as it is on Ubuntu with similar (or lesser) hardware, but at work I have to use certain servers allocated to me.

To use Thin with Sinatra, simply install Thin, and Sinatra will use it. If you need further help configuring Apache or Nginx, post more questions (after searching the web, of course).

Answer (score 2):

If you want easy, stay with WEBrick.

If you want a production server, go with [Apache + Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/). But that won't be as simple as just using WEBrick.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not answer you want but: http://rubyinstaller.org/. Installation is easy - follow instructions to install rails.

Second step is enable/configure port/application in firewall. Because ruby server works on port 3000 but http is common on port 80.

BUT this RoR environment is for development, so don't expect high performance.